# Why can't I read in a requests body this way?

Tags: go

This is a contrived example.

Why doesn't the .Read method read the response body's bytes into my byte slice?
"Read reads up to len(p) bytes into p. It returns the number of bytes read (0 <= n <= len(p)) and any error encountered."

Why doesn't this request read any of the data into p?

```
func Fetch(){
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://swapi.dev/api/people/1",nil)
        if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }

    req.Close = true // closes the request once the request has been made

    // Transport caches connections for future use 
    var transport = &http.Transport{DisableKeepAlives: true}
    var myClient = &http.Client{Timeout: 10 * time.Second, Transport: transport}
    resp, err := myClient.Do(req)

    p := []byte{}
    a1, err := resp.Body.Read(p)
    // a, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body) // this works

    fmt.Println(a1)
    fmt.Println(err)
    fmt.Println(p)
}
```

Comment: io.Reader and its Read method are idiomatic in Go and they just work that way. For the  reason: What would happen if the server sends you 47 Exabyte of data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, it does work as specified.

As mentioned in the `io.Reader` docs ([Link](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader)):

```
Read reads up to len(p) bytes into p.
```

In your case you defined a byte slice of length zero, so zero bytes are read from the response.

You can verify this by printing the length of p:

```
p := []byte{}
fmt.Printf("len of p: %d\n", len(p))
```

To create a non-zero-length byte slice you could use `make()`:

```
p := make([]byte, 4096)
```